# Java Generics - argument type and casting

Tags: java, generics

I have a generics problem I am trying to resolve. I'm doing some manual casting and it feels like I'm doing something wrong. I'm a bit new to using generics, so it's very much possible I am misusing them in some capacity. Some guidance would be very much appreciated.

**TLDR:**
I have an interface with a generic method that takes a `T` argument. I'm implementing this interface in a class, but in the implementer I would like to ensure `T` is of a specific type (lets say `Animal` so I can extract some fields). How can I do that?

---

**Details**:
I have an interface `Transformer` below, and an implementing class where `SpecialTransformer implements Transformer`.

`Transformer` has this definition:

```java
public interface Transformer
  public <T> Event transform(T input);
```

whereas `SpecialTransformer` has this definition:

```java
public class SpecialTransformer implements Transformer

  @Override
  public <T> Event transform(T input) {
    Animal convertedInput = (Animal) input; // <------- This feels wrong

    String color = convertedInput.getColor();
    //Other field based logic
  

  }
```

Comment: `T extends Animal`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of putting the generics constraint on the method, you should put the constraint on the interface (and the class):

```java
public interface Transformer<T> {
  Event transform(T input);
}
```

and on the class you either put a new generic type constrained to `Animal` and its sub-classes (or implementations):

```java
public class SpecialTransformer<T extends Animal> implements Transformer<T> {

  @Override
  public Event transform(T input) {
    String color = input.getColor();
    //Other field based logic
  }
}
```

Or even plainly use `Animal` as the type to `Transformer`:

```java
public class SpecialTransformer implements Transformer<Animal> {

  @Override
  public Event transform(Animal input) {
    String color = input.getColor();
    //Other field based logic
  }
}
```

You cannot achieve the same effect with the constraint on the method, because a method with signature `<T> Event transform(T input)` cannot be overridden by `<T extends Animal> Event transform(T input)`, because this would be the equivalent of overriding a method `transform(Object input)` by `transform(Animal input)` which does not meet the interface contract.

On the other hand, if you expect all your `Transformer` implementations to accept `Animal`, then you could use `<T extends Animal> Event transform(T input)` in your interface (or `public interface Transformer<T extends Animal>` in my suggested form).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. It turns out I was on the right track, but got confused in terms of the specific Syntax I needed to use. Your clarification really helped, thanks again Mark!